# PHP can not find my class?

Tags: php

How can I specify the exact absolute path?

File is here.  I specified it like this:

```
include "/home/core/public_html/d/core/source/class.Control.php";
```

Yet it tells me it is not.

***Fatal error: Class 'Control' not found in /home/core/public_html/d/core/source/class.ControlEntry.php on line ***

Code:

```
 <?php 
class ControlEntry
{
    private $control_object;

    function __construct( $control_object )
    {
        $this->control_object = $control_object;
    }
    public function actuate()  
    {   
        if( isset($_POST['ajax_type']) )
        {
            $this->control_object->ajax( $_POST['ajax_type'] );
        }
        else
        {
            $this->control_object->reload();
        }
    }
}
include "/home/core/public_html/d/core/source/class.Control.php"; // Can not find this f***ing file even though it is there.
$control_entry_object = new ControlEntry( new Control() );
$control_entry_object->actuate();
```

**Troubleshooting List**

Comment: Maybe the class simply isn't in that file?

Comment: perhaps you are looking at the wrong line, the error is for another class

Comment: Try using `require` instead of include, then you'll get an error if the file's not found. At the moment, it just looks like the class isn't found.

Comment: Are you using Zend framework or CodeIgniter?

Comment: If you only have one class per file you are calling the wrong file. You are calling class.control.php and error is for class.controlEntry.php

Comment: Load them in the correct order. Did you even read my answer?

Comment: Please post class.Control.php as well.

Comment: How doe PHP look for inlcudes?

Comment: As in the answer I mistook not finding and a class for not finding a file...this has been resolved.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The error originates from `class.ControlEntry.php`. Make sure you load `class.Control.php` before you load ControlEntry.

Answer (score 1):

You're including `"/home/domain/public_html/d/core/source/class.Control.php";` but the error says `/home/domain/public_html/d/core/source/class.ControlEntry.php`. Are you sure you're including the right file or instantiating the right class?

Answer (score 1):

That is the absolute path. It doesn't look like a bug. Actually it says the Class was not found. It doesn't say the file wasn't found. I guess in your class.ControlEntry.php line 3 references to Control. You need to include the file that contains control before using it.

Comment: there is a difference between calling and including. You need to include the code file (with 'include') that defines the class. Then you can call/use Control.

Comment: if you're working on a linux machine (and i guess you do) i'd ask you to check whether the web-server user has rights to read that file / directory. For testing purpose you could just `chmod 777 *` in /home/core/public_html/d/core/source/.

Also is /home/core/public_html/d/core/source/ inside your www-root?